# Policy of archivelog backup using redundancy politcy?

Tags: backup, rman

For example. If I create a policy using `configure retention policy to recovery window of 5 days` all backups before the 5 days will be obsoletes (datafiles, archivelogs backup etc..)

But, if my policy to be configured using `configure retention policy to redundancy 2`, only backupsets about datafiles will be obsolete and the backup of archives not.

My question is, is there some way to make the rman understand when the backup of archivelog don't have either "father" incremental backup  or a "father" full backup and isn't more necessary?

Usually in my routines I need create something like this to delete the archivelog backup that isn't more necessary (let's think that my retention is of two backups full in every sunday).

```
delete backup of archivelog until time=’sysdate-16′
```

Resume:

Is there some way to make RMAN understand when the archivelog backup isn't more necessery?

Comment: The version is 12c R1

Comment: The "delete obsolete" command will delete all backupsets and archivelogs that are not needed to satisfy the retention policy. How are you deleting the obsolete backups? How do your scripts determine which backups are not needed anymore?